# Missing Material Issue; Pink Color in Render Mode

Tags: rendering, materials

I made a simple image in Inkscape to go into the background of the shot to make it look as though the robot was in space. However, when I go to add it through the materials tab, it shows up as pink whilst rendering. I looked into the problem and tried to troubleshoot on my own by using the File >>> External Data >>> Find Missing File and it still did not want to show up. I have attached the file extensions and the Blender UI while I am editing for anyone who needs it.

Thanks to anyone who can help. I am sure this is a simple fix that a beginner like me cannot figure out.

[image: Blender UI]

[image: File Extension]

[image: Shader Nodes]

Comment: Can you post a pic of your node setup under the shading tab?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Done! Does that help any?

Comment: Interesting, I must say I don't think I have ever seen an empty "color space" box before. What happens if you click on it, can you select sRGB or linear or anything?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I changed it to all of the different drop down options and nothing changed...

Comment: There has to be something wrong with the image then. Maybe try starting from scratch? Add a new image texture, select the file and connect it up - maybe it will help Blender "remember" the path to the image.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I tried doing that, but it still doesn't want to work. I went back to the file and it must have become corrupted when I switched it to a .jpg file. I used those files for another project that worked just fine. So I went back into Inkscape, and re-exported it, and it worked great. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the image is not corrupt before adding it into Blender. If this happens, re-download or re-export the image.

Answer (score 0):

In the first image you posted go to the color space and set it to something. It is not supposed to be blank

Comment: I went through all of the options available on the drop down and none of them did anything to fix it...

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it the UV way, unrap it.